# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter for cucumber 4.3.1

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I'm using cucumber-java 4.3.1 with gherkins 5.1.0
When I execute my script with maven command "mvn test" its works fine but when i try to execute single feature file its gives "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter"

I have tried using different versions of Gherkins dependencies but still getting same issue. Following are my maven dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber3-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding only below 4 jars and then execute your feature file directly. It works for me from eclipse IDE as well as mvn test command

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options=src/test/java/features/test.feature
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```